# How to move rows from one SQL table to another SQL table with additional columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a SQL stored procedure that needs to move rows from `Table0` to `Table1`.  `Table1` has a schema that is exactly the same as the schema of `Table0`, with the exception that there is an additional INT column called `DataIndex`.  The value to be inserted into that column is computed at the beginning of the procedure.  Suppose that it's always 100 for the sake of discussion.

I've written the following SQL to try to do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT *, 100 AS INT_COLUMN_VALUE
FROM Table0;
```

When I run this code, I get the following error: Invalid object name 'INT_COLUMN_VALUE'.

How can I make this work?  My database is running MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: just remove the column name - `INT_COLUMN_VALUE` from your code, and try to run it, you probably don't have a column named `INT_COLUMN_VALUE`

Comment: I don't think you have to specify the column name when doing an insert.    More importantly, you should only make sure that you're selecting the same amount of columns as what is going into the table (unless you specify the columns as part of the insert command).

Comment: Ooops, I just realized that in my real code, I typoed the name of one of my tables

Comment: Above query on it's own can't produce that error. It has to be something else. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5750d/1

Comment: Just in case it isn't obvious, @NenadZivkovic is correct, and further, the column name cannot be causing this problem because the SELECT column aliases in an `INSERT..SELECT..` are no-ops, they have no effect  on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would Use the column name to make sure data lands into the right column by doing something like this..

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1,Column2,Column3,.....Int_Column) --<--- Int Column in destination table
SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,..... CAST(Col4 AS INT)      --<--- Computed column Cast as int
FROM Table0;
```

And you do not need to give an alias to the INT column, just make sure you mention all the columns in INSERT INTO statement and SELECT the columns using Column names in the right order as you have mentioned in the INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the column name - `INT_COLUMN_VALUE` from your code, and try to run it(you probably don't have a column named `INT_COLUMN_VALUE`).
- You don't need to specify it in your select statement.
- It is preffered to specify the column names in the insert statement.